# Binary package for Windows built with 'pkgbuild' doesn't include vignette and ignore listed files/folders in .Rbuildignore

Tags: r, windows, r-package

I'm under Windows and I tried `pkgbuild::build(binary=TRUE, vignettes = TRUE)` to build a binary package for Windows. There are two problems:

- the files/folders listed in `.Rbuildignore` are not ignored
- the vignette, that I built with `devtools::build_vignette` (if I correctly remember) disappears, it is not in the binary package

How can I build a binary package for Windows, including the vignettes, and ignore the files/folders listed to be ignored?